# Creating a custom "event" for a constructor

Tags: javascript, events

I am trying to create a custom "event" and I place this inside quotes because it won't be like a regular event per se from the events constructors.

So what I'd like to do is this

```
animate.addEventListener('animationReadyState',function(e){
  if(e.readyState == "complete")
    {
       console.log("Done");
    }
});

var animation = animate(document.getElementById('element'),{
                    left:"+200px",
                    top:"+200px",
                    easing: {
                      effect: "easeInOutBounce",
                      elasticity:1.5
                    }
                 });
```

My problem is how to fire off the "event"? I have the `readyState` changing throughout my code my problem is firing off this "event".

As of right now with using the events contructors I only get one readyState change fired off which is the complete. But I have others

```
initialising
invoked
animating
complete
```

No others are firing off.

Example of my Events Constructors:

```
var animateStateChange = new CustomEvent('animateStateChange',{ 'state' : null });

function initAnimate(){
   animateStateChange.state = "initialising";
   document.dispatchEvent(animateStateChange);
}
```

The problem with this is I'd have to do `document.addEventListener` or the `element.addEventListener` though putting the event listener on the element that is animating seems logical I'm not sure how to make it only fire from the element and not say on document... Maybe a little crash course on Custom Events or maybe a "hack" event firing system, even examples I can see logically.

This may give a better example of what I am looking for if you to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y74etqw3/)

Comment: Just don't dispatch it on the `document`, but on the element that you want?

Comment: I've updated with a jsfiddle to better get what I am looking for. I'm not really intrigued with the custom events constructors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if my solution will answer your query, but i tried to use custom events considering situation given above. Also, I see that there is some glitch in dispatchEvent returned value if any handler is provided. Separately i try to return false from handler, but that too din't worked. Below might help you to understand javascript custom event a bit :

Check this link for working code:

http://jsfiddle.net/3q0vubyp/1/

```
var animation = animate(document.getElementById('element'),{
                left:"+200px",
                top:"+200px",
                easing: {
                  effect: "easeInOutBounce",
                  elasticity:1.5
                }
             });
function handler(e){
    if(e.detail.state === "complete"){
            alert('Complete State');
            return false;
            //e.preventDefault();
            //e.stopPropagation();
        }
}
function animate(element, anim){
    var i=0;
    var j=true;
    var state=['initialize','invoked','animating','complete'];
    element.addEventListener('animateStateChange',handler);
    while(j){
        var animateStateChange = new CustomEvent('animateStateChange',{ 'detail' : {"state": state[i++]} });
        //if(!element.dispatchEvent(animateStateChange)){
        //  j=false;
        //}
        element.dispatchEvent(animateStateChange);
        if(i==4)
            j=false;

    };
}
```

In docs of dispatchEvent,[doclink](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.dispatchEvent) It is clearly mentioned that the return value is **false** if at least one of the event handlers which handled this event called **Event.preventDefault()**. Otherwise it returns **true**. That din't worked for me. 
Hope that helps!

Comment: I understand them for the most part just seems to not fire when it should. So I was maybe looking for a custom take on this by invoking a function which would fire off when I wanted it to

Comment: @EasyBB So You don't want animate function to fire custom event?..or some other custom function which is just for firing custom events.?

Comment: Please look at this, maybe this can give a better example of what I want... http://jsfiddle.net/y74etqw3/